# How to set and change GitHub workflow output

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to figure out how to set an output, change the output, then use it it the following job. I've tried making this as simple as possible yet the last echo returns true. The documentation doesn't provide examples so any insight or advice would be great.

```
  job-1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      compare: true
    steps:
      - name: set output
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=compare::false"
  job-2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # require the first job to have ran
    needs: compare
    steps:
      - name: echo job-1 compare output
        run: |
          echo ${{ needs.job-1.outputs.compare }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned you have to declare the value of compare in run and use an id

```
 job-1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      compare: ${{ steps.job_id.outputs.compare}}
    steps:
      - name: set output to false
        id: job_id
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=compare::false"
  job-2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # require the first job to have ran
    needs: compare
    steps:
      - name: echo job-1 compare output
        run: |
          echo ${{ needs.job-1.outputs.compare }}
```